# Simple Injector - Registering ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, simple-injector

I've been following this article to try and get ASP.NET Identity working with Simple Injector, but I've been running into some issues.
https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597

I setup my `SimpleInjectorInitializer` class to look like this:

```
public class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static Container Initialize(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = GetInitializeContainer(app);

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }

    private static Container GetInitializeContainer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        //container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        container.RegisterInstance(app);

        container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>();

        container.Register(() => new ApplicationDbContext("Your constring goes here"), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(container.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>()), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.RegisterInitializer<ApplicationUserManager>(manager => InitializeUserManager(manager, app));

        container.Register<SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>, ApplicationSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Register(() => container.IsVerifying ? new OwinContext(new Dictionary<string, object>()).Authentication : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication, Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        return container;
    }

    private static void InitializeUserManager(ApplicationUserManager manager, IAppBuilder app)
    {
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        //Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator()
        {
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 3;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my app I get the error `To be able to use the Lifestyle.Scoped property, please ensure that the container is configured with a default scoped lifestyle by setting the Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle property with the required scoped lifestyle for your type of application.`.

To fix this, I tried adding `container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();`  If I have that line though I get the error:

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>
> -[Lifestyle Mismatch] ApplicationSignInManager (Web Request) depends on ApplicationUserManager (Transient).
>
> -[Short Circuited Dependency] AccountController might incorrectly depend on unregistered type ApplicationSignInManager (Transient) instead of SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String> (Web Request).
>
> -[Short Circuited Dependency] ManageController might incorrectly depend on unregistered type ApplicationSignInManager (Transient) instead of SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String> (Web Request).
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] ApplicationUserManager is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] ApplicationSignInManager is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>
> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String> (Web Request) maps to the same implementation (ApplicationSignInManager) as the registration for ApplicationSignInManager (Transient) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.
>
> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for ApplicationSignInManager (Transient) maps to the same implementation (ApplicationSignInManager) as the registration for SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String> (Web Request) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.

I'm at a loss of what to do next, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The warning shows you full description just read it. For instance, it is not right to inject transient into scoped, also you inject concrete type `ApplicationSignInManager` instead of injecting abstraction which is `SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String>` etc etc

Comment: I did read it, but when I'm following the guide from the Simple Injector website I don't know where else to look to get it fixed.

Comment: to fix the first warning you need to register `ApplicationUserManager` as scoped **or** `ApplicationSignInManager` as transient. Try it

Comment: What's the difference between scoped or transient?  I ended up changing it to `container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);`

Comment: In ASP world scope is a request lifecycle. So you will instantiate your service only once per request

Comment: Transient will be instantiated each time constructor called, even though id you call it during one http request cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of error information given by Simple Injector can be a bit overwhelming, but you can distill the information down to two separate problems:

- `ApplicationUserManager` is registered as Transient
- Types incorrectly depend on unregistered type `ApplicationSignInManager` (Transient) instead of `SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String>` (Web Request).

You should certainly read the [Diagnostic Services documentation page](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics) in the Simple Injector documentation and especially read about [Lifestyle Mismatches](https://simpleinjector.org/dialm), [Disposable Transient Components](https://simpleinjector.org/diadt) and [Short-Circuited Dependencies](https://simpleinjector.org/diasc) to understand what Simple Injector is warning about and how to fix the problem.

In short, the fix is two-fold:

1. Change the registration of `ApplicationUserManager` from `Transient` to `Scoped` to prevent it from having a too-short lifetime and to ensure it is disposed of. Also read [this part of the documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/lifetimes) to learn the difference between Transient and Scoped from the context of Simple Injector.
2. Make sure that types (i.e. `AccountController` and `ManageController`) don't depend on `ApplicationSignInManager` (in their constructor), but instead depend on its base type `SignInManager<ApplicationUser, String>`.

Comment: Thank you Steven.  I know # 1 is probably pretty simple, but how do I change it to Scoped?  Is that the `container.RegisterInitializer...` line I need to change?
For #2 I updated the constructor.  Can I remove the SignInManger property from both controllers?

Comment: #1 Like this: `container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);`

Comment: #2 Yes, please do remove the properties. There are not needed. From a design perspective, the official template is a piece of sh*t.

Comment: Yeah I've always authentication with AD, but for this project I had to make the switch to ASP.NET Identity and so far I haven't been a fan.  I'm sure once I get it setup it'll be fine, but so far it's been a pain in my a**.